# Hillshade error: output values all equal 180

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.5, hillshade

I am having trouble producing a hillshade using the ArcGIS spatial analyst (hillshade) tool. I am working with a 1m DEM in a projected coordinate system (GDA_94_MGA56) and have adjusted the Z-factor accordingly for a metric dataset to 0.0000898 (dataset is at -28 degrees). Everytime I try to output, all values in the raster are returned as 180. Any ideas please?

[image]

and the output looks like so:

[image]

Comment: How does it look without z adjustment? You've made all elevations close to 0.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned by @FelixIP, you need to ignore the Z Factor. Leave it at 1.

From the [**documentation**](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/hillshade.htm):

> If the input raster is in a spherical coordinate system, such as
>   decimal degrees, the resulting hillshade may look peculiar. This is
>   due to the difference in measure between the horizontal ground units
>   and the elevation z units. Since the length of a degree of longitude
>   changes with latitude, you will need to specify an appropriate
>   z-factor for that latitude. If your x,y units are decimal degrees and
>   your z units are meters, some appropriate z-factors for particular
>   latitudes are:
>
> ```
> Latitude     Z-factor
>  0           0.00000898
> 10           0.00000912
> 20           0.00000956
> 30           0.00001036
> 40           0.00001171
> 50           0.00001395
> 60           0.00001792
> 70           0.00002619
> 80           0.00005156
> ```

It seems that this is where you got the value of 0.00000898. However, if your latitude is at -28 degrees, then, it seems reasonable that you should have used the value for 30 which is 0.00001036. However, *that is only if your x,y coordinate system is in decimal degrees*.

You're using the projected coordinate system GDA_94_MGA56 which has x,y units of metres. Therefore, you can use the default value of 1 because the elevation of the DEM is also in metres (presumably).

Also from the documentation, the z factor is the:

> Number of ground x,y units in one surface z unit.
>
> The z-factor adjusts the units of measure for the z units when they
>   are different from the x,y units of the input surface. The z-values of
>   the input surface are multiplied by the z-factor when calculating the
>   final output surface.
>
> If the x,y units and z units are in the same units of measure, the
>   z-factor is 1. This is the default.
>
> If the x,y units and z units are in different units of measure, the
>   z-factor must be set to the appropriate factor, or the results will be
>   incorrect. For example, if your z units are feet and your x,y units
>   are meters, you would use a z-factor of 0.3048 to convert your z units
>   from feet to meters (1 foot = 0.3048 meter).